# Issue with panTo() and how to change coordinates

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, pan

I've got a little issue while placing a `panTo()` into google maps V3.  Here is the description of the problem:

In this case, everything goes well, the map moves and animates until it stops at the right point.

```
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: strHtml });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
 {

 var latitude = marker.position.lat();
 var longitude = marker.position.lng(); 

 var panningPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); 

 activeInfoWindow.close();

 map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

 infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 activeInfoWindow = infoWindow; 

 });
```

In the other case, I wrote down the map go to the panning point I decided, but instead of animating the map, it just REFRESHES (not animate) and get a similar function to "SetCenter".

```
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: strHtml });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
 {

 var latitude = marker.position.lat();
 var longitude = marker.position.lng(); 

 var panningPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); 

 activeInfoWindow.close();

 map.panTo(panningPoint);

 infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 activeInfoWindow = infoWindow; 

 });
```

[image]

Why? Are there any  differences from `getPosition()` and collecting lat and long and redrawing a point?

My real problem is that I must pan not right on the point but "x % " bottom for top div overlay problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ... no-one? Really? X_X